# Magento password encrypt in my custom module

Tags: magento

I am new to magento.

In my site, I want to create new profile module.

In my new module have like this fields also

- current password
- new password
- confirm new password.

By default the password stored encrypt password like this `24d2f566950ed1af94c01d1ec5ce0f48:2e`.

My Question is `How to encrypt password like this in magento?`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a password hash like Magento does it you can use the Encryption model in Core like so:

```
$password = 'test';
$encrypted = Mage::getSingleton('core/encryption')->getHash($password);
```

If you'd like to validate the encrypted value with the plain password you can do so using the same model:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/encryption')->validateHash($password, $encrypted);
```

Comment: Because encryption model can be different (in Enterprise for example) I would advise to get the model with `Mage::helper('core')->getEncryptor()`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace encpt password in database "admin_user" table with all default setting:

temp password: admin123#

encpt password: 3bfea6f5ac1c57c3ce9a9165338cbc5c:CA1Byy3NifFoWVhjBxI3mD2bgAnj4qn7

sometime it does not work on Chrome:
http://www.customerparadigm.com/easy-fix-for-chrome-magento-admin-login/
Thanks